# xslt parameter error in a href link

Tags: asp.net, xslt

```
<xsl:value-of select="jobpageno"/>
```

above code do not have error, it can be success run and display page.

however, below code got error, after remove &PageNo={@jobpageno}, then success to display.

```
<a href="http://www.hello.com/description.aspx?ID={@id}&PageNo={@jobpageno}" target="_top">
```

what's wrong with this link containing this parameter

An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 58, position 103

it should show hello.com/description.aspx?ID=753561&PageNo=1

```
<a href="http://www.hello.com/description.aspx?ID={@id}&PageNo={jobpageno}" target="_top">
```

also got error

pageno is just one of element

```
<jobresults jobcount='1'>
<header1><![CDATA[ IT Jobs]]></header1>
<header2><![CDATA[1 Results for ' IT' in Asia]]></header2>
<entity id='753561' index='1'>
<position><![CDATA[Ecommerce Project Manager]]></position>
<jobCountry><![CDATA[Singapore]]></jobCountry>
<posteddate><![CDATA[January 2013]]></posteddate>
<JobDefaultRole><![CDATA[Contract]]></JobDefaultRole>
<jobTypeDesc><![CDATA[Jobs In IT]]></jobTypeDesc>
<jobDetails><![CDATA[ Ecommerce Project Manager Client Description Our  ...]]></jobDetails>
<jobpageno><![CDATA[1]]></jobpageno>
</entity>
</jobresults>


 <xsl:for-each select="jobresults/entity">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td>
                      <a href="http://www.hello.com/job-description.aspx?jobID={@id}&jobPageNo={@jobpageno}" target="_top">
                        <xsl:value-of select="position"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="jobpageno"/>
                      </a>
                    </td>
```

Comment: It would help if you actually stated what the error you are getting is, as this always provides useful information. Thanks!

Comment: Also, can you show the output you are actually getting from your transform.

Comment: i updated a xml output which pass to xslt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XSLT file must be well formed XML so you need to escape the `&`:

```
<a href="http://www.hello.com/description.aspx?ID={@id}&amp;PageNo={jobpageno}" target="_top">
```

The actual error message you're seeing is because the parser sees `&PageNo` as the start of an entity reference but then can't find the terminating semicolon.

Comment: i use ; when request.querystring["ID"] got wrong thing, 752781;jobPageNo=2;jobPageNo=

Comment: @OvO are you using `;` to separate the items or `&amp;`?  It should be the latter, and if you use that, ASP.NET should be able to handle the values just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It may be just a typo in your question, but in your first XSLT sample you use **pageno**, which means it is an element, but in your second XSLT sample you do **@pageno** which means it is looking for an attribute.

Perhaps you mean to do this:

```
 <a href="http://www.hello.com/description.aspx?ID={@id}&PageNo={pageno}" target="_top">
```

Note, there is nothing actually wrong with the syntax of your XSLT sample. If you reference an attribute that does not exist, it will just be output as a blank, and all will happen is the href attribute will not be complete as you expect.

EDIT: From looking at your amended question, there is neither an attribute or an element called **pageno**. Perhaps you mean to use **jobpageno**?

```
 <a href="http://www.hello.com/description.aspx?ID={@id}&PageNo={jobpageno}" target="_top">
```

Comment: same error after remove @, An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 58, position 103

Comment: Perhaps it is because your XML contains "jobpageno" and not "pageno"?

Comment: actually i am using jobpageno, i use pageno to post here, it is not the problem whether they are the same name

Comment: The problem is the `&` before PageNo. It has to be `&amp;` or else the XSLT is not well-formed. That's why the error message mentions entities.

Comment: Ah yes, you are spot on there. I couldn't see the wood for the trees, as they say....